# Nested Weights in a layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-layout-weight

I have a layout and I want the components to fill up the remaining part of the screen (using weights). The Listview works perfectly.

The 2 buttons at the end work the way I intent them to work also, however I get a warning which says "Nested weights are bad for performance".

I think it's a problem because I already used a weight parameter for the Listview, because when I remove the listview the warning is gone.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listMessages_messages"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#000000" >
        </ListView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:visibility="invisible" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnNewConversation_message"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
                android:layout_weight="50"
                android:onClick="newConversation"
                android:text="@string/NewConversation" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I want to know what i did wrong. a.k.a. what's causing the warning. since i want to use this in multiple places of my application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this code. Im not getting warning

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="10">
    <ListView android:id="@+id/listMessages_messages"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dip" android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dip" android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:layout_weight="8" android:background="#000000">
    </ListView>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px" android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="10" android:layout_weight="2">
        <Button android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="5"
             />
        <Button android:id="@+id/btnNewConversation_message"
            android:layout_width="0px" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dip" android:layout_weight="5"
            android:onClick="newConversation"  />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

As you placing both views 
1.List View
2.Linear Layout (Two buttons)
you need to give weight property to adjust them properly and for horizontal divison for buttons also give some weight sum property to second linear layout divide it equally using weights. note within second linear layout i used width for buttons to 0px

Comment: thanks for the answer, i had trouble figuring out what you meant with the weightsum in your previous response. now i can get on working on my application.

Comment: If you're not getting a warning with that code then your IDE is misconfigured. Nested weights are exactly that, nested, simply adding a weightSum to account for them doesn't change that fact. Also, I don't understand why you're using all of those 0px width/height values when you should be using fill_parent, what's the reasoning there?

Comment: @Justin Buser - can you please provide a simple working example of nested weights, b/c they aren't working for me either, and you sound like you've got them down ?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question correctly the following is sol:
 (say some 10)
with in top layout give some weight to ListView like 5 or 6 
make sure the layout height property to set to 0px
create child Linear layout give remaining weight (i.e 10-weight of listview)
as layout_weight to child layout for child layout layout_height to be 0px
with in this layout place that two buttons .Hope this is what you need

Comment: that's close to the solution, but not entirely. In my view there shouldn't be a connection between the listview and the buttons regarding weight. the listview's weight is to let it fill up the remainder of the screen vertically (height) and the button's both have to fill up half of the screen horizontally (width).

Comment: In other words the Listview's weight should be for the outer linearlayout only and the weights for the buttons are for the linear layout they're inside and don't need to have any interaction with the listview.

Comment: You seriously understood what he was trying to say? I've read it five times and can't make heads or tails of it.